# TcpPrinterConnection fails to open

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, tcp, zebra-printers

I am trying to setup a connection with the Zebra Printer over wi-fi.
I've run through the Connectivity Wizard on the printer itself, and this has setup ip address and ports there.

Now, in my iOS project, I need to sent commands to this printer.

I execute this code:

```
func print(content: <some_content>) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            guard let connection = TcpPrinterConnection(address: "ip_address", andWithPort: 6101) else { return }
            guard connection.open() else { return }
            
            ... the rest of the code

            connection.close()
        }
    }
```

It never gets past the guard with `connection.open()`, because it retuns `false`. There's no way to get the error from that method, but console has the following:

```
[connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C4:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
[connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C4] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
TCP Conn 0x282ba04d0 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
[connection] nw_flow_add_write_request [C3.1 18.165.183.13:443 failed channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] cannot accept write requests
[connection] nw_write_request_report [C3] Send failed with error "Socket is not connected"
```

I am not sure why it complains on the un-opened connection when I literally try to open it.
Is this setup or code-based? Do you have any idea on how I can fix this?

Thank you for any input!